# pendrive partitioning issue gpt corrupted

Tags: partitioning

pendrive size has reduced.. this is what comes when i try to formate.. please help

/dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?

The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.  This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.  Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?

Not all of the space available to /dev/sdb appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 5105280 blocks) or continue with the current setting?

Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.

Answer (score 0):

alright, Lets just delete the Partition table and start over on the drive.

Lets start by grabbing gparted from the software center. once you open the software center up it should be located in the "Top rated" Area.

[image]

Install this app and let the installer run. While thats running lest go over to the disks utility which is a pre-installed application just search "disks" in the lens and launch it.

in this windows you should see all the hard drives in your system including the flash drive you have. let us go ahead and select the flash drive in the left column.

you should see something close to what I have. we want to un-mount the drive not eject it so we will select the stop icon under the partition layout.

[image]

now the install of gparted should be done so lets go back and make sure its complete and now search for it in the lens and launch it.

this program requires admin rights so you will need to enter your password to run it. once the program is up in the upper right find your drive and select it and you should have something close to this.

[image]

up at the top on the window you have several options select "device" and "create partition table" you will get a warning like below.

[image]

Warning!!!!! This will delete everything on the drive so make a backup if needed of the flash drive.

make sure the drop down has msdos as the table type and click "apply"

The drive will change then have unallocated space.

[image]

no we are done with gparted and you can close the windows now and we can head back to the "disks" program.

the disk program now shows we have entire drive of free space.

[image]

lets select the " + " button and create a new partition for use to write files in.

[image]

if you want to use 100% of the space of the drive make sure the bar is all the way across the top like mine and the other default settings should be ok for a fat32 flash drive. you can name your drive what ever you wish i just made mine called flashdrive. click create once done and your partition will be made.

[image]

our last step is to mount the drive with the play button and you should see the drive show up in the file browser and you can begin to write your data to it.